# Mobile View Port is not set in Google

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, media, viewport

I have developed the responsive website but Google tool is not showing mobile responsive only the home page rest other pages are showing responsive

- http://www.go4hosting.com/
- http://www.go4hosting.com/private-cloud.htm

I am checking on this [page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly)

Can anybody help me out why this is happening.

Comment: Fix the javascript issues with JQuery before asking google bot to check the page - it's probably errors that are causing it not to render.

Comment: The home page isn't responsive. When I resize my browser I have a huge horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks to all but this wasn't the reason. Page is actually getting redirected on US IP so it wasn't hitting the actual page which is showing. On US IP the page which was hitting wasn't done responsive that why it is showing the error on google. But thanks for you comment